# react-hook-form - Cannot pass form data to a parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using **react-hook-form** and trying to pass the data from a form to its parent.
For this I'm trying to pass the data via a callback, but it's not working.
When I console.log **data** inside the parent component, I get undefined.

**Parent component**

```
import React from 'react';
import InputForm from './InputForm';

const App = (data) => {
  const onFormSubmit = () => {
    console.log(data.name);
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
       <InputForm onceSubmited={() => onFormSubmit()} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Child component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const InputForm = ({ onceSubmited }) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    onceSubmited(data);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='name'
            ref={register}
          />

          <input
            type='email'
            name='email'
            ref={register}
          />
          
        <button type='submit'>
          Submit
        </button>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};

export default InputForm;
```

Comment: You wanna try `<InputForm onceSubmited={(data) => onFormSubmit(data)} />` for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the argument in your arrow function. This should make it work:

```
import React from 'react';
import InputForm from './InputForm';

const App = () => {
  const onFormSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data.name);
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
       <InputForm onceSubmited={(data) => onFormSubmit(data)} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: you still getting `undefined`?

Comment: Now I get just an empty object.

Comment: I edited the answer. There was another arrow function without an argument

Comment: BTW a better way to do this is hoist the data into state and initialize it on the App level

Comment: Could you please show me how? I'm just trying to learn React.

Comment: Glad it's working now. Feel free to make this as the answer. Re showing: It really depends on what you want to use data for in the parent component. Changing state will re-render the component which only makes sense if you do something with it. Otherwise keep state as shallow as possible